# How to use the result of one formula in another formula?

Tags: python, function, math, return, formula

How do I use the result of one function into another function.

```
list = [1, 1, 1, 1]
def margin():
    a = 0
    b = 1.2
    c = 1
    for i in list:
        if i == 1:
            x = a + b - c
            return x    # x = 0.2


def calc():
    for i in list:
        formula = 2 + margin()
        print(formula)

calc()
# 2.2 2.2 2.2 2.2
```

I was hoping for the program to compute:

```
'''
          2  + 0.2 = 2.2
         2.2 + 0.2 = 2.4
         2.4 + 0.2 = 2.6
         2.6 + 0.2 = 2.8
giving result 2.2 2.4 2.6 2.8
'''
```

Comment: "How to use the result of one formula in another formula?" , is not the question here. As it is done correctly

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type. It won't cause a problem with this code, but it can lead to bugs that produce cryptic error messages.

Comment: Your `margin` function is a bit strange. It's not clear why you want to loop over that list. The function only returns a numeric value if it encounters a 1 in the list, otherwise it returns `None`, and if you try to use  `None` in an arithmetic expression you will get a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

```
def margin(element, a=0, b=1.2, c=1, default_margin=0):
    if element == 1:
        return a + b - c
    else:
        return default_margin


def calc(elements, start_value=2):
    formula = start_value
    for i in elements:
        formula += margin(i)
        print("{:.1f}".format(formula))


elements = [1, 1, 1, 1]
calc(elements)  # 2.2 2.4 2.6 2.8
```

### Programming good practices

1. Don't use builtin types as variable names (`list`)
2. Use arguments of functions and not global variables
3. Use default values and not hardcoded numbers inside functions for a more generic approach
4. Do not create unnecessary variables (`x` inside `margin` function)
5. Make sure a function always returns the same type of variable or at least document and handle special cases
6. Be careful with iterating twice over the same variables (inside `calc` and `margin` function you are iterating the list, so the first element in the list is the only one being used).

Comment: Thank you for typos and print formatting @ChristianKönig

Comment: Thank you Adiro, I am new to python and I will remember your advice, could you explain the last part which says: print("{:.1f}".format(formula)), is it possible to print this in a simpler method that I could easily understand.

Comment: That part was actually @ChristianKönig 's edit, but I can explain it. `print()` is a function that accepts many types of variables and sends it to the console. I was using `print(formula)` as you did, but this would print a `float`. `"{:.1f}".format(formula)` converts the `float` into an `str` printing just one decimal digit, while the other version could print more decimals, as `float` is not an exact decimal representation and `2.2` may be stored as `2.19999999` or `2.20000001`. So summing up, that part enforces to print a single decimal.